# Script with path in Filemaker Pro 12

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, script, path, filemaker

I'm using OS X 10.6 & Filemaker Pro 12; I'd like to have a script in FM to automatically open a .pdf file from a container field using Preview (dumping the file on the desktop) but it has to be using a variable path for whomever is using this particular hosted file in our local (or remote) office network

Answer (score -1):

I see that this question is a little old, but for anyone who comes across it now looking for help...

It sounds like what you need is the "Get ( DesktopPath )" function, as part of a Set Variable script step.  It would be something like this (in pseudocode):

```
Set Variable $filepath ( Get(DesktopPath) & "filename.pdf")
Export from field ( FieldWithPDF, No Dialog) {{NB: check the box that says "Specify output file" and set it to "$filepath"}}
```

Also, be aware that if you're in a mixed environment (Windows & Mac), you may need a slightly more complicated Set Variable statement to accommodate for different path notations (see http://www.filemaker.com/11help/html/create_db.8.32.html).

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We have no rules against answering old questions here. All knowledge is worth having.